# Problema al ejecutar .jar en mi pc

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, netbeans, launch4j

tengo un proyecto que tiene una conexión con phpmyadmin y  al momento de correrlo funciona todo bien pero al momento de crear mi .jar solo me abre mi login y cuando le doy en iniciar sesion se me cierra automaticamente, alguna idea de que podrá ser? Intente tambien hacer mi .exe con launch4j y al prinicipio tenia un error con las librerias externas donde no reconocia my conector mysql pero lo logre arreglarlo  y ahora me pasa lo mismo, mi programa no pasa del login. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

ESTA ES MI CLASE CONEXION

```
package simassaneamiento;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import simassaneamiento.vistas.Login;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class ConexionMySql {
 public Connection conexion;
 public Statement sentencia;
 public ResultSet resultado;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
     //   conectar();
    // ConectarBasedeDatos();
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setVisible(true);

    }

    
    public boolean ConectarBasedeDatos(){
 try {
 final String Controlador = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 Class.forName( Controlador );
 final String url_bd = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/bd_saneamiento2";
 conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url_bd,"root","");
 sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(), "Error ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
     return true;
 }
    
     public void DesconectarBasedeDatos() {
 try {
 if (conexion != null ) {
 if(sentencia != null) {
 sentencia.close();
 }
 conexion.close();
 }
 }
 catch (SQLException ex) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 System.exit(1);
 }
 }
 public Connection getConnection(){
 return conexion;
 }
 
 public ResultSet seleccionar(String sql)
 {
     
     ResultSet resultado = null;
     try{
         sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
         resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
         
     } catch(SQLException sqle)
     {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese el numero de cuenta");
     }
     return resultado;
 }
 
 //agregar metodo ejecutar
 public boolean ejecutar(String sql) throws SQLException
 {
     boolean estado = false;
     try{
         sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
         sentencia.execute(sql);
         sentencia.close();
         estado = true; 
         
     } catch(SQLException sqle ){

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al ejecutar la consulta");
     }
     return estado;
 }

}
```

ESTE ES MI LOGIN

```
package simassaneamiento.vistas;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import simassaneamiento.ConexionMySql;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButIniciarS = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextContra = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButIniciarS1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        jButIniciarS.setText("Iniciar Sesión");
        jButIniciarS.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButIniciarSActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButIniciarS.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jButIniciarSKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/Asset-4hdpi-1.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 153));
        jLabel2.setText("BIENVENIDO");

        jLabel3.setText("Usuario:");

        jLabel4.setText("Contraseña:");

        jButIniciarS1.setText("Salir");
        jButIniciarS1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButIniciarS1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jButIniciarS)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 309, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextUsuario)
                            .addComponent(jTextContra, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jButIniciarS1))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextContra, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButIniciarS, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButIniciarS1)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButIniciarSActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         boolean estado = false;
        try
        {
            ConexionMySql Con = new ConexionMySql();
            String u = jTextUsuario.getText();
            String c = jTextContra.getText();
            Con.ConectarBasedeDatos();
            String SQL = "SELECT usuario FROM login WHERE usuario = '" +u+"'" +
               "AND contraseña = '" + c + "'";
            Con.resultado = Con.sentencia.executeQuery(SQL);
            if (Con.resultado.next()){
             //   if (Con.resultado.getString("i").equals("1")){
                    setVisible(false);
                    jFramePrincipal jframe = new jFramePrincipal();
                    jframe.setVisible(true);
                    estado = true;
                    
                    if( estado = true )
                    {
                          jFramePrincipal principal = new jFramePrincipal();
                          principal.setVisible(true);
                          Login ventana = new Login();
                          ventana.setVisible(false);
                          ventana.dispose();
                          
                    } 
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta.");
                this.jTextContra.setText("");
                this.jTextUsuario.setText("");
            }
            Con.DesconectarBasedeDatos();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta.");
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                            

    private void jButIniciarS1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
           int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( Login.this, "Terminar programa?",
         "Aviso", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );
           if ( res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
               System.exit( 0 );
           else if ( res == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION )
              this.isVisible(); // this hace referencia a un JFrame y lo cierra
    }
```

Comment: Se que si hace la conexión porque si le ingreso algún otro usuario o contraseña incorrecta me dice que esta incorrector pero al logearme me saca u.u

Comment: También cabe mencionar que en mi administrador de tareas me aparece como si estuviera corriendo el programa

Comment: Podría ser cualquier cosa sin ver el código, ¿Podrías proporcionar algo de código para poder ayudarte? Ej la clase que realiza la conexión, algún controlador que gestione el evento del Login o si se esta intentado pasar de una ventana a otra, estos pueden causar posibles fallos.

Comment: Listo ya actualice mi pregunta.

Comment: Me fui a la pestaña de output cuando limpio y contruyo el proyecto y me aparece esta linea en rojo

Comment: Note: C:\Users\verif_zopru1\Desktop\proyecto\NetBeansProjects\simasSaneamiento\src\simassaneamiento\vistas\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Pero no utilizo ningún método absoleto.

Comment: Posiblemente esa nota es porque estas usando ``getText()`` de un JPasswordField lo cual si esta obsoleto por temas de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos errores en las siguientes partes, primero en el método `jButIniciarSActionPerformed` estas creando varias instancias de jFramePrincipal.

Luego mas adelante estas haciendo `ventana.dispose()` pero es una nueva instancia de Login por lo cual una nueva ventana de logeo, si la intención de esto es cerrar la ventana de Login que ya estaba abierta tendrías que hacer `dispose()`

En el constructor de la clase Login se debe configurar la accion al cerrar, agregar

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

La intención de esto es que al cerrar el programa, se cierre ralamente y no quede en "segundo plano" ocupando memoria

Después de que la base de datos dio un resultado correcto:

```
jFramePrincipal principal = new jFramePrincipal(); // Se abre la siguinte ventana
principal.setVisible(true);
            
dispose(); // Se cierra la ventana de login actual.
```

Se cierra la ventana de login y se abre la ventana principal.